# Will OLE DB driver for ODBC work on ProgressDB?

Tags: odbc, oledb, progress-db

I am preparing a small piece of software to connect to a database. Unfortunately I have not access to the database right now and would like to prepare as much as possible. The client has a ProgressDB database, I found out that the not so well known database uses ODBC. The software I am preparing uses the Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers.

Can I assume that this driver will work on the ProgressDB with the correct settings applied, because they are both using ODBC?

It's unfortunate I can't find much info about ProgressDB's.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

What version of Progress?  Generally speaking ODBC will work reasonably well with version 9 and better.

V9 was released in the late '90s.  Version 10 was released in 2004 and rebranded "OpenEdge".  The current release is version 11.

Depending on what version you have and what was installed you might need to download the ODBC (or JDBC) drivers.  You should be able to get them via your ESD (Electronic Software Delivery) account at Progress.com.  On the bright side they are free.

Comment: The Progress version is 9.2. Thank you for your answer. I found that i need an extra driver. Posting the answer tonight when I am free.

Comment: FWIW, there is no 9.2.  9.1E Service Pack 4 was the last release of Progress 9.